# How to make Bitmap on Image Button stretch evenly

Tags: android, image, android-button

Here is my image xml description

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:onClick     = "@{() -> viewModel.onButtonClick()}"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:background="@{viewModel.thumbnail}" />
```

viewModel.thumbnail returns a size reduced bitmap image.

The problem is the image gets deformed when attached to image button

See below result.[image]

All checker board in these image should be perfect square

How do I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the src property and some sort of scale type

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:scaleType

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:onClick     = "@{() -> viewModel.onButtonClick()}"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:src="@{viewModel.thumbnail}" />
```